# How to walk on Frames/IFrames and Subframes with Selenium

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver, frames

I'am doing an automated test with selenium and got some problems when walking on frames and iframes.

I have this setup

```
<iframe id="1">
    <iframe id="2">
        <frame id="3">
           <a id="4">
```

I wish to walk all this path with selenium until i reach the id="4".

My tests were:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("1"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("2"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("3"));
```

and

```
driver.switchTo().frame("1");
driver.switchTo().frame("2");
driver.switchTo().frame("3");
```

The problem is, it doesn't pass to frame 2(on both cases), it enters the first frame but the frame 2 cannot be found.

Is there a way to do it diferently? iframe seems different from frame to selenium, but how I work with both?

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:** Found more information, pls review. Still need to access the same divs, 1, 2, 3 and 4, but the iframe I need to access(2) is inside a div.

```
<iframe id="1">
    <iframe id="anotherframe"></iframe>
    <iframe id="anotherframe1"></iframe>
    <div id="outside>
        <iframe id="2">
             <frame id="3">
                <a id="4">
             </frame>
       </iframe>
    </div>
    <iframe id="anotherframe2"></iframe>
</iframe>
```

I'am sorry about that, its too much code haha

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

After like 90 tests I got it working, the main problems were not the Selenium commands, but the page itself, it loads dynamically and it has random id's.

I just had to use one thread.sleep(30000); to wait this looong time to make it appear, after that it walked like a charm.

Thanks a lot for your help, your comments gave me new ideas on how to use it =)

Comment: maybe something like this: http://pastebin.com/hhQqAeJ4 ?

Comment: It doesn't worked, still didn't found the second ID, I think thats is because its another iFrame. 

Thanks for the try friend!

Comment: Is possible that they are on the same level? or maybe you have another iframe tag before.

Comment: Check my edit pls, now it's the entire code. If it's inside a div how can I get the reference?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It shouldn't matter that it's inside a `DIV`, it should still be found. Are you sure that it's visible or not in another `IFRAME`?

Comment: can you find `<div id="outside>` tag after you switch to `<iframe id="1">`? What do you mean "the frame 2 cannot be found."? You got any exception?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, edited my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After like 90 tests I got it working, the main problems were not the Selenium commands, but the page itself, it loads dynamically and it has random id's.

I just had to use one thread.sleep(30000); to wait this looong time to make it appear, after that it walked like a charm.

best option:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("1"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("2"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("3"));
```

Thanks a lot for your help, your comments gave me new ideas on how to use it =)